# Need advice for graphics editor programs for use in Android App Development

Tags: android, animation, graphics, android-animation

I am a developer who picked up the Android SDK and am going through it trying to teach myself how to use that. My question isn't about that. I have some ideas for apps that aren't games but would require some pixel animation. I am terrible with that but my best friend is a good artist and is willing to pick up new software to help out. Can you guys suggest anything for him to pick up to create animated pixel art?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for good pixel animations. I recommend "Pyxel Edit" from Stephan Hövelbrinks. It can be found [here](http://pyxeledit.com/), and is a very good pixel animation software. It is also only around 10$